# I want change URL in facebook.

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I want change URL in facebook. Now URL is http://www.facebook.com/pages/work/399241663472504  redirect into http://www.facebook.com/work/399241663472504 How to do this???

Comment: You can get help from Facebook for user / account / site problems at https://www.facebook.com/help/?page=220217228006012 - this is not the correct forum for those questions (see http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/faq#questions  for more information)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do using Facebook functionality is setting page's short name.

To do that, navigate to https://www.facebook.com/username while logged in as page administrator.